# OpenCV Split and Merge

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an image of type `Mat` that I am trying to separate into its individual bands so I can then adjust the pixel values in each band separately. When I write the code this error pops up "No matching function for call to 'cvSplit'".

```
Mat image = imread(file,1);
Mat rBand, gBand,bBand;
cvSplit(image, bBand, gBand, rBand, NULL);
imshow("red", rBand);
imshow("blue", bBand);
imshow("green",gBand);
```

Comment: cvSplit and most (I think all) functions that start with cv and then the function name belong to the C API which is deprecated and should not be used. What you are looking for is  [cv::split](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=compare#split) which is from the C++ module and accepts cv::Mat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A mat does not allow a subscript operator if not stated when created. Therefore most create a Mat denoting number of bands within so it can then be split. this means that `Bands[0],Bands[1],Bands[2]` are each of a single channel and are grayscale. Not get original image must then merge the channels using `merge` function.

```
Mat image = imread(file,1);
Mat Bands[3],merged;
split(image, Bands);
vector<Mat> channels = {Bands[0],Bands[1],Bands[2]};
merge(channels,merged);
imshow("red", Bands[2]);
imshow("blue", Bands[0]);
imshow("green",Bands[1]);
imshow("merged",merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function instead if `cvSplit`:

```
cv::split
```